# Rails/ActiveRecord: Can I establish polymorphic relationships with tables with differing id types?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Establishing a many to many polymorphic association is a real head twister. I've already spent the afternoon on this and I'm running out of energy.

I have two models, `Comment` and `Project`. I have a third model `Badge`. A user can react to a comment or project by adding a badge. Comments and projects will be `reaction_targets`.

I think I understand how to do the many to many polymorphic part. The trouble is `Comment` and `Project` have different id types. `Comment` is indexed by `bigint` whereas `Project` uses `uuid`.

My join table is called `reactions` through which `Badge` points to `reaction_targets`

```
    class Badge < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :reactions
      has_many :reaction_targets, through: :reactions
    end
```

Each row in the join table points to a badge and a target.

```
    class CreateReactions < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
      def change
        create_table :reactions do |t|
          t.references :reaction_target, polymorphic: true
          t.references :badge
        end
      end
    end
```

I've established that the association with `reaction_target` is polymorphic.

```
    class Reaction < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :badge
      belongs_to :reaction_target, polymorphic: true
    end
```

I point `Comment` at the join table.

```
    class Comment < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :reactions, as: :reaction_target
      has_many :badges, through: :reactions
    end
```

Everything works correctly:

```
    > b = Badge.first_or_create(name: 'badge')
    > c = Comment.create
    > c.badges
    #=> []
    > c.badges << b
    #=> (0.2ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1...
```

However things are different when it comes to `Project`.

I establish the association in the same manner:

```
    class Project < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :reactions
      has_many :badges, through: :reactions
    end
```

But it doesn't work the same.

```
    > b = Badge.first_or_create(name: 'badge')
    > p = Project.create
    > p.badges
    #=> #<Badge::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x3fdc34cde54c>
```

The first thing I see is that `#badges` returns an object other than an empty array.

And when I try to add a badge to the collection, I get an error:

```
    (1.5ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
    : SAVEPOINT active_record_1
    from /Users/123/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:75:in `async_exec'
    Caused by PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
    from /Users/123/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:75:in `async_exec'
```

I can see in `schema.rb`, `reaction_target_id` is expected to be a `bigint`.

```
      create_table "reactions", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string "reaction_target_type"
        t.bigint "reaction_target_id"
        t.bigint "badge_id"
        t.index ["badge_id"], name: "index_reactions_on_badge_id"
        t.index ["reaction_target_type", "reaction_target_id"], name: "index_reactions_on_reaction_target_type_and_reaction_target_id"
      end
```

I assume the error above is because of that. Is it possible to establish polymorphic relationships with tables that have differing index types? If so, what do I need to do to be able to add badges to projects? If not, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `as: :reaction_target` on the `has_many :reactions` association in Project.

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reactions, as: :reaction_target
  has_many :badges, through: :reactions
end
```

This is what specifies the polymorphic association which you declared as `reaction_target`.